# Tabulizer extraction missings

Tags: r, tabulizer

I'm using `extract_tables` from the `tabulizer`-package to extract tables from a PDF file. Everything works fine but if the table is with less than 4 lines with headers it's not extracted. If table is more than 4 lines it's properly extracted.

This is the code that I use :

```
text <- extract_tables("file path, file name")
table <- do.call(rbind, text)
table <- as.data.frame(table)
```

I also  tried solution with fixing area:

```
text <- extract_tables("file path, file name", area = c(0,0,595,842))
```

But in this case some columns are missing and some columns are merged.

Did someone face the same issue and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried the `columns` argument? Anyway in my experience `tabulizer` is never 100% reliable...

Comment: I think you should add the `tabula` tag to your question, and you will be a bit more likely to get answers (`tabula` is the Java library used by `tabulizer`).

Comment: This is an old question, but recently struggling with similar issue and found that the pdftools package can be used to locate the area input to extract_tables and improving the reliability considerably. I wrote a blog post walk through. https://redwallanalytics.com/2020/04/07/tabulizer-and-pdftools-r-libraries-as-super-powers-part-2/